# group by error in my query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering if perhaps someone could shed some light on the below error. The sql works fine locally but i get the the below error remotely.

SQL query:

```
$inQ = "
    SELECT category.category_name, GROUP_CONCAT(subject.subjects SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects
    FROM category 
    INNER JOIN tutor_category_subject ON tutor_category_subject.category_id = category.category_id
    INNER JOIN subject ON tutor_category_subject.subject_id = subject.subject_id
    WHERE tutor_category_subject.tutor_id = $tutorId AND tutor_category_subject.category_id = $categoryId
";
```

MySQL said:

> #1140 - Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error says:  You cannot mix group columns and non-group columns without a GROUP BY clause.  Try adding one:

```
SELECT category.category_name, GROUP_CONCAT(subject.subjects SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects
FROM category 
INNER JOIN tutor_category_subject ON tutor_category_subject.category_id = category.category_id
INNER JOIN subject ON tutor_category_subject.subject_id = subject.subject_id
WHERE tutor_category_subject.tutor_id = $tutorId AND tutor_category_subject.category_id = $categoryId
GROUP BY category.category_name
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want this:

```
SELECT category.category_name, GROUP_CONCAT(subject.subjects SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects
FROM category 
  INNER JOIN tutor_category_subject ON tutor_category_subject.category_id = category.category_id
  INNER JOIN subject ON tutor_category_subject.subject_id = subject.subject_id
WHERE tutor_category_subject.tutor_id = $tutorId AND tutor_category_subject.category_id = $categoryId
GROUP BY category.category_name, subject.subjects
```

You need the `GROUP BY` clause added to get your select to be able to use `GROUP_CONCAT`.